# Body diodes in MOSFET symbol

Tags: mosfet, symbol

As I understand, all MOSFETs have body diode. But I see some symbols have body diode shown while some not. Is there a difference in such MOSFETs?

Comment: Are you sure the other symbols are MOSFETs, rather than JFETs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no difference.  There is no "official" MOSFET symbol, just variations on a theme.  The diode will always be there regardless.

The symbols with a diode explicitly shown are very useful when the diode itself is an important part of the circuit, to serve as a reminder as to which way the diode is biased.

Comment: It would be possible to construct a discrete MOSFET where the source and drain each had an independent body diode connecting to a common "body" terminal which was separate from the source, drain, and gate.  This is usually not done within an IC because efficient construction requires that every NFET have one terminal in common, and having the base terminal common to all NFETs is less limiting than would be having the source or drain be common. With a "discrete" NFET, however, it's most advantageous to have the bulk substrate be the drain; having the base be separate from the source would...

Comment: ...reduce the amount of metal available to carry source/drain current.

Answer (score 4):

There is not. It is accepted that the body diode is reverse biased in diagrams where it is not explicitly shown.